# Bootstrap space between rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to put some space between rows with buttons (three buttons in each row). In my example each row is inside `div` element marked with bootstrap class `btn-toolbar`.

I know I can solve this problem with using inline styling and put parameter like `margin-top` or writing custom css class but I am wondering if there is some bootstrap class for this?

Code:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <br/>
  

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:30px;">Nazaj</button>


  
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>

  

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>

  
  
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:1px;"/><h2 style="display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;padding-left:3px;">/</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:1px;"/>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>

  

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" ></span></button>
 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Shrani</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use form-group class with btn-toolbar

Comment: This works. Please post it as answer. Perhaps you know if there is a way with bootstrap only to increase / decrease spacing between rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  **form-group** to give space of 15px to give vertical space.

If you want to give space between col-md-column-* use **col-md-offset-***

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <br/>
  

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:30px;">Nazaj</button>


  
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>

  

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>

  
  
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:1px;"/><h2 style="display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;padding-left:3px;">/</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:1px;"/>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>

  

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" ></span></button>
 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Shrani</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="btn-toolbar form-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar form-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-toolbar form-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
</div>
```